# How to stop sass/compass evaluating "not print" in media query as "false"

Tags: sass

As you can see, sass/compass parses not print and turns it into false - breaking the media query.

```
$ cat test.scss
@media (not print) and (min-width: 600px) {
  color: #000;
}
$ sass test.scss
@media (false) and (min-width: 600px) {
  color: #000;
}
```

I've tried using `unquote` but it doesn't want to cooperate either

Comment: It is according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries And even if it doesn't, I'd still like to know how to do it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

## The Sass reason

When Sass encounters parentheses, it will attempt to evaluate the contents.  The *not* keyword is used for negation, so when it sees `not print`, that evaluates to `false`.

So, you try to use the string `'not'`.  If it was anywhere *other* than in a media query, it would work.

```
.foo { color: (#{'not'} #000); }
```

Evaluates to

```
.foo {
  color: not #000;
}
```

Media queries *are treated special* in Sass and must adhere to the general format of media queries.

## The CSS reason

Even if you *could* generate the desired CSS, it is invalid.  If you read the MDN page you're using as reference, it specifies the following:

> The not keyword cannot be used to negate an individual feature query, only an entire media query

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

So no, it is not possible to specify that your styles will be used by devices that have a minimum viewport width of 600px *and* are not print.