# Compass, sass, media queries. "767px is not a valid css value"

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, compass-sass

I'm writing some sass classes for a bootstrap-based website. Basically, I want to generate some helper classes. In this case, they are media-queries and flex.

For each bootstrap screen size, (only, maximum or minimum) I want to add a "order" value from 0 to 12.

There are 3 dimensions.

- the screen size (xs, sm, md, lg) : [SS]
- screen size boundary (maximum, minimum or only) : [SB]
- the flex order (0..12) : [FO]

ex :

[SS]-[SB]-flex-order-[FO]

will give
xs-only-flex-order-0
xs-only-flex-order-1
xs-only-flex-order-2
xs-down-flex-order-0
xs-up-flex-order-0
........

To do this, I wrote this

```
$xs: (
  name : 'xs',
  min-size: 700,
  max-size: 1000
);
$sm: (
  name : 'sm',
  min-size: 1001,
  max-size: 1200
);
$sizes: $xs, $sm;


@each $size in $sizes{
  @for $i from 1 through 12 {

    $name : map-get($size, name);
    $min-size : map-get($size, min-size);
    $max-size : map-get($size, max-size);

    .#{$name}-only-flex-order-#{$i} {
      @media all and (min-width : $min-size) and (max-width : $max-size){
        order : $i;
      }
    }

    .#{map-get($size, name)}-down-flex-order-#{$i} {
      @media((max-width : map-get($size, max-size))){
        order : $i;
      }
    }
    .#{map-get($size, name)}-up-flex-order-#{$i} {
      @media((min-width : map-get($size, min-size))){
        order : $i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Though, I get an error  `(max-width: 767px) isn't a valid CSS value.`

It stepped through the first media query block and threw at the first media query block `(max-width : $max-size)` it encountered.

Seems to me that `@media (max-width: 767px)` is a perfectly valid css value.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is this really the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem?  There are a lot of undefined variables here, I shouldn't have to initialize them all (or download/import Bootstrap to get them).

Comment: Oh you're right I'm sorry. I'm going to reduce that.

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've accidentally created a mapping by using an extra set of parentheses.  While the syntax for mappings looks somewhat similar to the syntax for media queries, they are not valid here.

This:

```
.#{map-get($size, name)}-down-flex-order-#{$i} {
  @media((max-width : map-get($size, max-size))){
    order : $i;
  }
}
```

Should be this:

```
.#{map-get($size, name)}-down-flex-order-#{$i} {
  @media(max-width : map-get($size, max-size)){ // minus a set of parentheses
    order : $i;
  }
}
```

Related: [How to stop sass/compass evaluating "not print" in media query as "false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630140/how-to-stop-sass-compass-evaluating-not-print-in-media-query-as-false)